# Vim: pipe register to external command

Tags: vim

How can I pipe the contents of a register to the standard input of an external command? I intuitively tried the following, but it doesn't work (may serve to illustrate my need, though):

```
:"0w !some_command
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If contents of the register does not happen to contain NULs then it is as simple as

```
call system('some_command', @r)
```

. Problem is not so simple once you acknowledge the fact that register contents may have NUL byte inside: in this case you need to use `getreg()` and force it to produce a list form of register (this is what second `1` to `getreg()` does)

```
call system('some_command', getreg('r', 0, 1) + (getregtype('r') isnot# 'v' ? [''] : []))
```

. This form will preserve NULs which may happen to live inside register. Note though that `getreg('r', 0, 1)` will not have trailing newline even if you copied text in linewise mode which is why I have written `+ (getregtype('r') isnot# 'v' ? [''] : [])` to add it (form `@r` does not have this problem).

A list form is a way to represent binary data predating the time blobs were introduced. To convert random binary data into this form you split it at NL bytes (preserving any resulting empty strings) and then replace all NUL bytes to NL.

Comment: Just what I wanted! Didn't know `system()` took a second argument.

Comment: @ZyX is it possible to avoid the `call system()` for instance `:.!awk{print $0}` would pipe the current line to `awk`, that will just print it back. Is it possible to do something like `:""!awk{print $0}` ? i.e.  pipe the content of `""` to `awk`.

Comment: @AlexanderCska Why would you want to avoid `call system()`? You can now avoid the issue with NULs by using `call system('some_command', getreg('r', 1, 1))`.

Comment: @ZyX it looks simpler to me.

Comment: What's the purpose of the `1, 1` arguments to getreg?

Comment: @mazunki I have updated the answer with that. It also seemed like my first edit left first sentence in inconsistent state with the rest of the answer, so I corrected that.